# Design patterns to avoiding memory leaks with Backbone app

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, memory-leaks

In my backbone application's router, I use a closure to store an instance of a view that requires authentication. The idea is that when the application first loads, the router will cache the current view request if it requires authentication and then query the server to check if the current user is authenticated. When the authentication request is complete, the view stored in the closure will render.

Using Chrome's memory management profiling tools, I see that this design pattern creates a memory leak. What is a better design pattern to achieve this same functionality without creating a memory leak?

```
if (session && !app.session.is_authenticated()) {
     //if view requires authentication and is not logged in, then listen for login events
     (function(that, viewContent) {
         that.listenTo(app.session, "authenticated", function() {
             that.mainView.renderPageContent(viewContent);
         });
     })(this, viewContent);
} else {
    this.mainView.renderPageContent(viewContent);
}
```

Comment: I'm not clear on why you're doing this. What is it you're trying to accomplish?

Comment: @kinakuta. I'm trying to delay rendering a certain view that requires an authentication event until after the user is authenticated. This is in a situation where the user logs in and then refreshes the page. The view will wait to render until the server returns the user object. I am not currently using localStorage, so need to re-retrieve the user object on a page refresh.

Comment: When you say "page refresh", what do you mean? How can you be keeping any js variable around through a page refresh? I think I'm still not clear on the scenario.

Comment: @kinakuta. The variable is not persisted through a page refresh, the current session variable is refetched from the server. The viewContent holds a backbone View that is instantly created by the router when a page is loaded. However, it is not rendered until the new session variable is fetched from the server, trigger the authenticated event.